# how can download fileStream with angular from asp.net core

Tags: angular, .net-core, angular-httpclient

hi every body I want download file with angular 7 and my back end is .net core
here is my back end code:

```
[HttpPost]
public FileStream DownloadPack([FromBody]string gridplusSelectedData)
{
try
{
var updateData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UpgradeViewModel>(gridplusSelectedData);
var getdateofGettingFiles = DateTime.Now.GetHashCode();
var selectedPPatch = @"G:\PackTemp\" + getdateofGettingFiles;
var mngfile = new CreatePatchCustomForCustomer();
var result = mngfile.CreatePatchFolder(updateData.GeneralInformation.GeneralStatus, updateData.GeneralInformation.AllDependencies, updateData.GeneralInformation.PriorityList, selectedPPatch);
// return new File(result, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "PatchDirectory.zip") ;
// return File(result, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip , "PatchDirectory.zip");

return new FileStream(result, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

return null;
}
}
```

here is my front end Code

```
public downloadPatch() {
  let previousData = this.configService.finalObjForDownloadPack
     this.configService.post("PackPatchManager/DownloadPack", previousData,"zip").subscribe(blob => {
     saveAs(blob, 'PatchDirectory.zip', {
        type: 'text/plain;charset=windows-1252' // --> or whatever you need here
     });
  });

}
here is my front end Service
  public post(url, body, mode?): Observable<any> {
    let httpOptions
    if (mode == "zip") {
      httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'responseType': 'blob' })
      }
    }
    else {
      httpOptions = {

        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })

      }
    }

    return this.http.post(this.serverAdress + url, body, httpOptions);
  }
```

then I am getting this error:[image: errorPic]

my request and response :[image: chrome]

my http post request go to error and not go to success

Comment: `responseType: 'blob'` shouldn't be a HTTP header. It should be one of the options of httpOptions. And settijg the content type to JSON is useless. HttpClient does it for you when you post an object or array.